# storyboards vs nibs in team environment

Tags: ios, storyboard, nib

I was reading the big nerd ranch book on ios development and it is a year old so only addresses ios5 but they advised against storyboards arguing that in a team environment the storyboard file often will have source control conflicts due to too many people trying to update one file, and that when you have more than a few view controllers it gets cluttered, and that the things it helps with like segues are not that difficult to do without storyboards.

I wondered if anyone can share experience of using storyboards in a team environment and whether they have a preference vs nibs

Answer (score 1):

even .xib's (nibs) are very dangerous to use in a team environment because any form of merging can be extremely hard to impossible and many times requires simply accepting one set of changes and redoing the other. Because using .xib's is more localized in general it will be safer than a story board but if you have a heavily edited file it can be worth doing all UI in code so that all changes can be merged easily.

Answer (score 0):

As rooster117 pointed out, XIBs can have the same issue as Storyboards in a multi-developer environment.

There are a few things you can do to mitigate the complications, but the biggest thing is to realize your development team has to work as a "team" and communicate with each other. We already work in a system where multiple developers can't really go in and do major modifications to the same files at the same time. We just have to recognize XIBs and Storyboards require a bit more communication.

Another way to mitigate the issue is, use multiple storyboards. I'm not talking about 1 item per Storyboard, that defeats the purpose; but you don't have to stick the whole app in a single Storyboard. Break it up into flows and put each flow into a different Storyboard file. If you are working in different flows, no issues, and if you are working in the same flow you are mostly likely talking a lot so it should be less likely to cause a problem.

XIBs would limit it the most, but it's probably overkill for most teams/projects.